# ros-foxy-serial no longer available?

Tags: serial, ros-foxy

I wrote a ros2 project a while ago to communicate with arduino using ros serial library which I think was ros-foxy-serial.
It is simple rclcpp project to read data from arduino using `#include <serial/serial.h>` .

Recently I tried to build the project and got these errors

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findserial.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "serial", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "serial" with any
  of the following names:

    serialConfig.cmake
    serial-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "serial" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "serial_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "serial"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I am running both foxy and noetic and found there is no foxy version of ros-serial exist in apt.
Is this just temporarily gone or removed permanently?